# How to check if the flash message set is empty in cakephp

Tags: css, cakephp, model-view-controller, flash-message, cakephp-2.x

I have a login form and i am setting the flash message on invalid login like this in the controller:

```
$this->Session->setFlash(__('Invalid username or password'));
```

And displaying the message like below in ctp file :

```
<div id="error" >
<?php
echo $this->Session->flash();
?> 
</div>
```

CSS for the div is as follows:

```
    #error {
    padding:10px;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-right: 18px;
    font-size:16px;
    font-weight:600;
    position:relative;
    top:20px;
    }
```

When the page is loaded an empty flash message is shown.
How to check if `$this->Session->flash();` is empty and display div only if its not empty??

When the message is empty flash message on page load it looks like this:

[image: When the message is empty flash message on page load it looks like this :]

Similar way it looks like this when message is set:

[image: Similar way it looks like this message is set:]

Comment: Why in ```.ctp``` just display it from the controller's method.

Comment: I need custom design for that

Comment: How to do it ??

Comment: Follow http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog-auth-example/auth.html#authentication-login-and-logout

Comment: I have tried that but it didnt work as expected

Comment: So is there any option to check if flash message is empty??

Comment: First try to debug into else part and see is your method going to else. Then you can debug $this->Session.

Comment: I have checked that too.

Comment: @aavrug  Check the screenshots i have added.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131119/discussion-between-aavrug-and-varuni).

Comment: Just don't set an empty flash message. You try to work around a problem you caused. So fix the real issue and fix setting an empty flash message instead working around the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

Create your Custom Elements with **Error Alert**, **Success Alert**, etc...

**/View/Elements/error_alert.ctp**

```
<!-- Example Bootstrap Error Alert -->
<div class="alert alert-danger">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
    <strong><?php echo $message ?></strong>
</div>
```

**/View/Elements/success_alert.ctp**

```
<!-- Example Bootstrap Succes Alert -->
<div class="alert alert-success">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
    <strong><?php echo $message ?></strong>
</div>
```

In your **Views** add this, It´s appear only when Message must be displayed

```
 <!-- It´s will work for all alert types (not only for error alerts) -->
<div class="col-md-12">
    <?php echo $this->Session->flash(); ?> 
</div>
```

if you want use one add this in your controllers:

**For success Alert**

```
$this->Session->setFlash('Success message!', 'success_alert');
```

**For error Alert**

```
$this->Session->setFlash('Error message!', 'error_alert');
```

Comment: Thanks. This is the right answer. But i overrided the default style.